# Wikidata API: Check whether a Wikivoyage article is linked from Wikidata

Tags: mediawiki, wikidata-api

I want to programmatically check whether an English Wikivoyage article (for instance [Bronzeville](https://en.wikivoyage.org/wiki/Bronzeville)) is linked from the [Wikidata database](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Wikidata%3aIntroduction) or not.

For instance, the Bronzeville article at English Wikivoyage is NOT linked from Wikidata (even though the item [exists](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q4823292)).

Note: Some Wikidata items have labels, but that does not imply existence or non-existence, as some items have no label, and some items with the same label refer to two different things (for instance a place and a person).

Is there a way to do this, via the [Wikidata API](http://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php) or other?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `wbgetentities` method for this. To do this, ask it for the entity that's related to the desired article on enwikivoyage. For example, for an entity where the link exists ([Prague](https://www.wikidata.org/wiki/Q1085#sitelinks-wikivoyage)):

http://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&sites=enwikivoyage&titles=Prague&format=xml&props=

You get result like this:

```xml
<entity id="q1085" type="item" />
```

If the link doesn't exist (Bronzeville):

http://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&sites=enwikivoyage&titles=Bronzeville&format=xml&props=

The result is:

```xml
<entity site="enwikivoyage" title="Bronzeville" missing="" />
```

(The `props=` part of the query is there so that you don't get all the information about the entry, just whether it exists or not.)

Comment: Unfortunately in most cases that does not work, because Wikivoyage and Wikidata names are different VERY often (more than 50%). For instance, "Al Hudayda" on Wikivoyage is "Al Hudaydah" on Wikidata. "Akiu" on Wikivoyage is "Akiu, Miyagi" on Wikidata. Etc

Comment: That's what the `sites=enwikivoyage` parameter means: that the entered name is from Wikivoyage. For example http://www.wikidata.org/w/api.php?action=wbgetentities&sites=enwikivoyage&titles=Al%20Hudayda&props= (using the Wikivoyage name) works just fine.

Answer (score 3):

Whether a Wikivoyage article is linked from Wikidata or not can be found via a query like the ones below:

https://en.wikivoyage.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Bronzeville&prop=pageprops&format=jsonfm

https://en.wikivoyage.org/w/api.php?action=query&titles=Paris&prop=pageprops&format=jsonfm

If the response contains "wikibase_item", then it means it is linked.